# iPhone - Convert NSString encoding from WindowsCP1251 to UTF8

Tags: iphone, unicode, encoding

how can I have this conversion from `NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding` to `UTF-8`?
I had several attempts but no one worked as it should. My last try was:

```
NSData *dt = [mystr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *str = [NSString alloc] initWithData:dt encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
```

The result of `str` is unreadable. Did anyone encounter anything similar?

Comment: How do you obtain the CP1251 string in the first place?

Comment: In your code example, you first convert `mystr` from whatever it is to UTF-8, then you create a new string, but tell `NSString` that it's CP1251. Which is supposed to be CP1251?

Comment: @Bavarious : The string comes from socket connection.

Comment: @Phil : So how I create an NSString from my converted UTF8 data??

Comment: When you call initWithData:encoding:, tell `NSString` that it's `NSUTF8StringEncoding`...

Comment: In that way I get the same string as before conversion..

Comment: Given the sequence of bytes you get from the socket, send `-[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding]` or `-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]`, passing `NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding` as the encoding.

Answer (score 7):

I think you were so close:

```
// Convert it back to CP1251
NSData *dt = [mystr dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];

// Now load it as UTF8
NSString *str = [NSString alloc] initWithData:dt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: The last one is wrong: Encoding must be the encoding of the data, so NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding. You should add that an NSString itself doesn't have an encoding (in practice).