# converting language characters [ios] using NSISOLatin1StringEncoding

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am pulling out some language sentences (in different languages) and displaying them in TableView (max 5 rows each row) and when user taps on any row, then I navigate user to a new screen and display full text there.

The problem that i am running into is, it is taking too much time to convert the characters to be visible properly on device.

I wrote the following code to convert the json text for each row:

```
NSString *msgDesc = [myContentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

char const *cStr = [msgDesc cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

msgDesc = [NSString stringWithCString: cStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Thanks for the help.

Regards,

Reno Jones

Comment: Please show the code of your "row for index path" method.

Comment: I've already posted above.

Answer (score 2):

Since conversion is taking too long, you should move it out from your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method into the code that pulls the data out from its data source, do the conversion there, and store it for future use.

Add `NSMutableArray *myContentsArrayConverted` to your class, then convert everything into it, and use in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of performing the conversion each time you must display your string:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != myContentsArray.count ; i++) {
    NSString *msgDesc = [myContentsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    char const *cStr = [msgDesc cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    [myContentsArrayConverted addObject:[NSString stringWithCString: cStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

Now you can replace the slow code with the much faster

```
NSString *msgDesc = [myContentsArrayConverted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Well, I thought about doing it, but never tried the same, however, I was doing in heightForRowAtIndexPath and was trying to replace this formatted string in my actual json for that particular row. Hence, next time whenever I will fetch from array, it gives me formatted one. is there any other way to display different language characters? other than allocing an nsstring and passing cstring to it.

Comment: @RenoJones Well, another alternative is to [go through `NSData`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8314908/335858), but I doubt that it would give you much of an improvement. When you calculate the height, do you call the `sizeWithFont:` method repeatedly? If you do, you may want to cache the number returned by it, because the call is not too speedy either, if I remember it correctly.

Comment: Yes, I am caching the height in the json Array itself, reusing the stuff with the best of my ability. I believe NSdata+NSString method is similar to the NSString+CString..