# iOS: Convert a string from little endiand to big endian

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, endianness

I got a string in **little** endian that I would like to convert in **big** endian.

This "647b" should become "7b64". How can I do this in **iOS** (C++ code welcome)?

**PS: I am deriving the string from a NSData object.**

Comment: Have you had a look at https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1667080-byte_order_utilities

Comment: Do you want to change memory location like concept of `endians` or just want to change string value  like that ?

Comment: What exactly is "647b"? Is it a string with four characters giving the hexadecimal representation of two bytes? Or is it the hexadecimal representation of some string internals? What are you trying to achieve anyway? Please better describe it. Most likely, you need to change the endiness in the NSData instance before any strings are involved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552864/bit-conversion-tool-in-objective-c 
Try to use this solution. @Codo you are right about my post.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you were converting your data into a NSString, so I have to make some assumptions here.

NSStrings (and CFStringRefs, which are toll free bridged) have encodings.  Many iOS devs don't need to keep in mind that their strings are UTF8Encoded.

[If you look at the list of string encodings from Apple ([CoreFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/cfstringbuiltinencodings?language=objc) & [Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1497293-anonymous?language=objc)), you'll see some of them do specify little-endian and big-endian.

And probably the best way to do what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
// load it as UTF16 big endian
NSString *str = [NSString alloc] initWithData:yourDataObject encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding];
```

[That line of code I found in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942830/iphone-convert-nsstring-encoding-from-windowscp1251-to-utf8).